# AdomdConnection is giving A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running error

Tags: c#, ssas

I'm using MSOLAP provider to connect Analysis Server. Hence I made a below connection string and try to establish a connection from app/web server to SSAS server

Connection String

```
Provider=MSOLAP.2; Data Source=172.16.53.3; Initial Catalog=Myyres;
```

Code Snippet Used

```
   AdomdConnection objAdomdConn = new AdomdConnection();
      objAdomdConn.ConnectionString = a_strConnSting;
      objAdomdConn.Open();
```

Error Occured

> *"A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running."*

Stack trace Output

```
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection+IXmlaClientProviderEx.ConnectXmla()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToXMLA(Boolean createSession, Boolean isHTTP)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.Open()
   at StackOverflow.AdoMD.button1_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

The same code is working while I running on SSAS server. I'm getting error only at calling from app\web server to SSAS server

Comment: what is the real value of `myserver`? You are not using `localhost`?

Comment: That is the name of the server. for example ip address of the ssas server machine.

Answer (score 0):

The Connection string Expected is

connectionString = "Data Source=ServeName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DBName;";

To connect with Windows authentication add "Integrated Security=SSPI;" in connection string 
To connect with SQL authentication add "User ID=userID; Password=pwd;" in connection string